# Apache CXF and Spring but no WSDL (recursive links)

Tags: spring, cxf

I have written a small sample web service, using Apache CXF (CXFServlet) and Spring (ContextLoaderListener) I have registered the CXFServlet to listen on the `/` url. And I am declaring my beans in beans.xml.

When I start the web service with tomcat and go to the service url, then I can see the web service definition (e.g. methods, endpoint, wsdl link). But the problem is that when I click on the wsdl link, then I do not get the WSDL file, but instead I am recursively forwarded back to the same page, but each time the name of the web service address is appended:

1. localhost:8080/Test/accountEndpoint
2. localhost:8080/Test/accountEndpointaccountEndpoint
3. localhost:8080/Test/accountEndpointaccountEndpointaccountEndpoint

The service is a "code-first" service which a @WebService annotated java interface and a implementation class.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
            <display-name>cxf</display-name>
            <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
            <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
            <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />

    <bean id="account" class=".....AccountImpl" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="accountEndpoint" implementor="#account"
        address="accountEndpoint" />
</beans>
```

As I understand it, CXF should automatically generate the WSDL file and provide it to me, when I click on the link, so I do not understand why that is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the address this way, with a leading slash:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="accountEndpoint" implementor="#account"
    address="/accountEndpoint" />
```

Sorry, making a change, the above is not correct:

You are right, I am able to replicate the behavior with mapping CXFServlet to the "default" servlet path mapping of `/`, the fix that I could get to work for myself is to map it to `/*` instead:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If I do thatn, the the first address is: `localhost:8080/Test//accountEndpoint` (notice the double slash?), but the result is the same recursive link problem

Comment: You are right..able to replicate the behavior that you are seeing, the fix in my machine is to change the url-pattern in the servlet-mapping, not completely sure why it works with this change though - updated the answer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved it. But the first part is also correct, the address value needs a leading slash too, otherwise I get a 404, using both suggested changes it works.